# Displaying categories in order by name - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Use wordpress and I want displaying categories in order by name.

I pasted the function in file archive-product.php but displays the categories in order after ID

```
< ul class = "products" >
    <? php woocommerce_product_subcategories;? >
</ul>
```

So, modified the file wc-template-functions.php, but can not displaying by order name.

See the code:

```
NOTE: using child_of instead of parent-this is not ideal due to the silverside WP bug (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15626) pad_counts won't work
$product _ categories = get_categories (apply_filters (' woocommerce_product_subcategories_args ', array (
' parent ' = $parent > _ id,
' menu_order ' = > ' ASC ',
' hide_empty ' = > 0
' hierarchical ' = > 1
' taxonomy ' = product_cat > ' ',
' pad_counts ' = > 1
) ) );
```

Comment: Does this help? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124770/how-to-order-the-get-categories-result

Comment: Helps? http://insider.zone/tools/client-side-url-redirect-generator/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$args = array(
    'order' => 'ASC', //or DESC
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'parent' => 0
); 
$terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

if ( $terms ) {
    echo '<ul class="products">';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
         echo '<li>' . $term->name . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: instead of <? php woocommerce_product_subcategories;? >

Comment: Don't displays anything.. :(

Comment: You have print the category list inside the loop, where I place comment?

Comment: I don't know..
I pasted the function from you instead of the function:
`<? php woocommerce_product_subcategories;? >`
So it looks like this:
  `<ul class="products">
   <?php $args = array(
    'order' => 'ASC' //or DESC
); 
$terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

if ( $terms ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
         //the loop
    } 
} ?>
  </ul>`

Comment: i've updated my code. You see that in loop i've added category name. Replace it in your code from all your

Comment: I have added the code but it doesn't work.
I commented structure < ul class = "products" > and </ul> but I display all categories and subcategories, is not ok.
I want to display only the parent categories in order by name and be inserted of the category link. 

`<?php 
$args = array(
    'order' => 'ASC' //or DESC
); 
$terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

if ( $terms ) {
    echo '<ul class="products">';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
         echo '<li>' . $term->name . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}?> `

Comment: Ok, I display the parent category, but it still doesn't display in alphabetical order by name and order by ID.. `Rover
Toyota
AUDI
BMW
CITROEN
FIAT
FORD
MERCEDES
OPEL
PEUGEOT
RENAULT
SEAT
SKODA
VOLKSWAGEN VW`

Comment: Ok, it's clear. Add 'orderby' => 'name' and it work for you. i've update already code